# Does SAMBA require 777 permissions on shared directory

Tags: server, permissions, samba

I am trying to create a samba share with a windows machine.  I have a user `John` who is part of the group `admins`. I am trying to share the path `/data/movies`  which is owned by the user `Marc` and the group `admins`

Originally I set the file permissions with sudo chmod 764 /data/movies

I then created a Samba share

```
[movies]
path = /data/movies
valid users = @admins, @homeusers
read only = yes
write list = @admins
```

I then try to access in from Windows User `John` and get an access denied message.  If I then give the group execute privalages with

```
sudo chmod 770 /data/movies
```

I can then gain access to the folder with user `John`

My question is, does Samba require execute privilege for any user accessing the share? Even just to read only? Or am I doing something wrong?  I would really like to avoid changing the permissions to `777` for all my shared folders.

Comment: Directory permissions differ from file permissions - the `x` permission on a directory makes the directory searchable by {owner,group.other}

Comment: makes perfect sense. thank you.

Comment: Of course this is not samba specific. You always need the x permission to enter a directory.

Comment: "Does SAMBA require 777 permissions on shared directory"  and "sudo chmod 770 /data/movies"  are not the same issue.